# Woocommerce - customize checkout fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I hope you guys can help me with a `woo-commerce` problem.

I used [this guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) to delete the entire checkout and replace it with my own. I use this code to delete the standard fields.

My problem is:
when I fill out the form, I keep getting this fail (*translated from Danish to English*): please fill out the address field to continue.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
 $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;

 return $address_fields;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your code works perfectly as expected (and it's the official WooCommerce code)… I have test it … it works! … **you should better update your question with your real related code,** than just pasting an official WooCommerce existing snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'xa_checkout_change_required_fields_to_optional' );
function xa_checkout_change_required_fields_to_optional( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
     $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
     $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;

     return $fields;
}
```

Try [like this](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-checkout-change-the-address-fields-property-from-required-to-optional/)